# Grails/Hibernate does not auto create tables on MySQL Linux

Tags: hibernate, grails

I run a Grails app successfully on Windows localhost. Then I deploy the war onto Linux. The whole app works correctly except Hibernate (I believe) has no wish for creating any table there:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
   could not execute query;
   ...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
   Table 'xxx.yyy' doesn't exist
   ...
(no other errors noticed)
```

Once I manually create all tables, the app works fine.

The question is **how to make the tables auto created?** Just as it should be.

Local MySQL:

```
MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for Win64 (x86)
```

The server's MySQL:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.24, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

File `/etc/tomcat7/context.xml`:

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/XXX" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx"
          username="xxx" password="xxx" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
          removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"
          maxWait="-1"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the hibernate property hbm2ddl.auto to 'create' in you're hibernate configuration file.

Comment: Setting `hbm2ddl.auto` (spelling!) in DataSources.groovy just helped me. Thanks! It looks like different environments has different default value for this parameter.